# image in the background of one table cell using website

Tags: html, image, background

I used to help design the emails at my old company but the digital marketer I used to use a website called 'backgrounds' to make one cell have a background that we could put text over.

What would happen is, i would slice the cell up in photoshop/illustrator that needed to have the text on the background and he would upload it to this website and it would give him the html for the link and then he would paste it into the email. I have an example of the code below but have no under idea what the website is that he previously used

```
  <!--Cell 4--><td background="cell_04.jpg" style="display:block; font-family:Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#000000; line-height:14px" bgcolor="#000000" width="214" height="181" valign="top">
                                                                                                  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                                                                                  <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:214px;height:181px;">
                                                                                                    <v:fill type="tile" src="cell_04.jpg" color="#000000" />
                                                                                                    <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
                                                                                                      <div style="font-family:Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#000000; line-height:14px">
                                                                                                  <![endif]-->
                                                                                                  <div class="auto-style1" style="font-family:Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#000000; line-height:14px">
                                                                                                      <br>
                                                                                                      Give someone you love the perfect Valentine’s Day gift with a beautiful and contemporary Spaceform piece engraved with your own words.
                                                                                                      <br>
                                                                                                      <br>
                                                                                                      The stunning quality of our pieces means they can be treasured forever and will always be a special reminder of how much you love someone.<br>
                                                                                                      <br>
                                                                                                          </div>
                                                                                                   <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                                                                                   </v:textbox>
                                                                                                  </v:rect>
                                                                                                  <![endif]-->
                                                                                                </td>
```

Does anyone know of the website he used or how this could be done better, remember we were not coders at the time of creating this code.

Comment: go to mailchimp.com and this is not a code question

Answer (score 0):

use background inside the style
background=url("path to image");

```
<td  style="background=url("cell_04.jpg");display:block; font-family:Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#000000; line-height:14px" bgcolor="#000000" width="214" height="181" valign="top">
                                                                                                  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                                                                                  <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:214px;height:181px;">
                                                                                                    <v:fill type="tile" src="cell_04.jpg" color="#000000" />
                                                                                                    <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
                                                                                                      <div style="font-family:Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#000000; line-height:14px">
                                                                                                  <![endif]-->
                                                                                                  <div class="auto-style1" style="font-family:Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#000000; line-height:14px">
                                                                                                      <br>
                                                                                                      Give someone you love the perfect Valentine’s Day gift with a beautiful and contemporary Spaceform piece engraved with your own words.
                                                                                                      <br>
                                                                                                      <br>
                                                                                                      The stunning quality of our pieces means they can be treasured forever and will always be a special reminder of how much you love someone.<br>
                                                                                                      <br>
                                                                                                          </div>
                                                                                                   <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                                                                                   </v:textbox>
                                                                                                  </v:rect>
                                                                                                  <![endif]-->
                                                                                            </td>
```